# LFTP to touch every file it's downloading

Tags: bash, lftp

I'm using lftp to run a backup job, from one location to another. And it's the only possible solution. But it works really great. I'm using this command:

`/usr/bin/lftp -c "open -p 9922 -u jdoe,passw0rd sftp://sftpsiteurl.com; mirror -c -e -R -L /source-folder /destination-folder/"`

But I need to change the greated date or modified date on the files comming down. Right now the date on the files is from the remote location. But I'm not sure  on how to do this. 
I can see that you can run some kind off script for validating the files coming down. But I'm unsure off the command, and I can't seem to find any examples.

Do anybody know if this is possible, and how to do it.

Comment: What about lftp? Doesn't it report its actions. May be you could parse the output to get the files to [touch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/touch). [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) is my personal favorite for such parsing jobs but [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)/[sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) might do as well. A small sample session could be helpful for an answer in detail.

Comment: An alternative approach (if parsing of lftp output is not possible/sufficient): You could do a `find . -type f -exec touch {} \;` to [touch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) every file. This would include the down-loaded as well as the previous existing. If this is not sufficient you may use [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to make a list of files before and after down-load. For the case, that existing files might be updated I would use [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to recognize changes in date and/or size.